# How to copy data from one table to another via preparedStatement using MySQL?

Tags: java, mysql, sql, copy, prepared-statement

I am having the following code:

```
String sql ="INSERT INTO table_a (some_num, text, popularity) "
             + "SELECT numero, text, count(text) FROM table_b GROUP BY numero, text";          
            PreparedStatement pstm = conn.prepareStatement(sql);
            pstm.executeUpdate();
```

table_a is a table in my MySQL server with the following construction: some_num INT(11) NOT NULL, text VARCHAR(255), popularity INT(11);

table_b is a TEMPORARY table in my code, with numero INT NOT NULL, text VARCHAR(255)

I would like to INSERT all the rows from table_b into table_a, but end up having the following error trace:

```
SEVERE: null
java.sql.SQLException: invalid new some_num data
at com.mysql.jdbc.SQLError.createSQLException(SQLError.java:964)
at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.checkErrorPacket(MysqlIO.java:3973)
at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.checkErrorPacket(MysqlIO.java:3909)
at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.sendCommand(MysqlIO.java:2527)
at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.sqlQueryDirect(MysqlIO.java:2680)
at com.mysql.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.execSQL(ConnectionImpl.java:2501)
at com.mysql.jdbc.PreparedStatement.executeInternal(PreparedStatement.java:1858)
at com.mysql.jdbc.PreparedStatement.executeUpdateInternal(PreparedStatement.java:2079)
at com.mysql.jdbc.PreparedStatement.executeUpdateInternal(PreparedStatement.java:2013)
at com.mysql.jdbc.PreparedStatement.executeLargeUpdate(PreparedStatement.java:5104)
at com.mysql.jdbc.PreparedStatement.executeUpdate(PreparedStatement.java:1998)
at Tester.main(Tester.java:67)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
String sql ="INSERT INTO table_a (some_num, text, popularity) "
         + "SELECT numero, text, count(text) table_b GROUP BY text";          
        PreparedStatement pstm = conn.prepareStatement(sql);
        pstm.executeUpdate();
```

What is the first column supposed to be?  Your result set is grouped by text and not numero, so you can't grab the numero column.

Comment: You are right, I re edited the question with numero, which is just a plain number thanks!

Answer (score 0):

try this way:

```
INSERT INTO table_a (some_num, text, popularity)
         SELECT numero, text, count(text) from table_b GROUP BY text
```

this working fine and tested.